# Twitter # tag feeds on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios

How can i show # tag feeds from twitter on iOS and Android ?
I tried using: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a twitter app!!
Twitter search API is a part of twitter [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) and out should Authenticate before you can get any  data from server.

look [search API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) and [twitter OAuth authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#v1-1)